# ERC20 Token Mist 0.9.0 . Balance not showing up

Tags: tokens

I am running [Ethereum Wallet and Mist 0.9.0](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) (released this on 24 Jul ).
ERC 20 token balance is not showing up even if Watch contact is in place. 
On the other hand, I can properly see ERC 20 token balance on my wallet using [ethplorer](https://ethplorer.io) and etherscan.

All seems to be sync with the Wallet. Any thought? 
Also to mention ETH balance is OK, just the ERC 20 token is missing.
Cheers!

Comment: is your chain synced?

Comment: Yes. this is the reason why I am asking why the balance is not displayed on the Wallet. All is ok on etherscan but not showing the balance on the Ethereum Wallet ... no clue

Comment: If the balance is showing on etherscan, the only possible reason, I could guess is your blockchain is not synced up to the block in which your transaction(the transaction in which you received token balance). Your eth balance is okay because you may have the block in which your account received the transaction of eth. Check the block number by `eth.blockNumber` from geth console to check your current block and match it my the latest block on any blockchain explorer loke etherscan.

Comment: Invalid TxHash 0x6a068169cd0e9d5a40962a5182060e0c91e2baf0 entered. iam using metamask wallet. it does not show balance in the etherscan

Answer (score 0):

The token balance must be called "balanceOf" in your contract in order for Mist to pick it up:

```
mapping (address => uint) public balanceOf;
```

You must also "Watch Token" under the Custom Tokens header on the contracts page.